# how to pass token to local storage with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, instance, react-query

I created an Axios instance to set up the baseURL and the headers. The header also needs to contain the token for authorization.

```
export const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY)}`
  },
  validateStatus: () => true
});
```

when the user logs in, I call an API to get some data related to the user using useQuery. When I log in, I try to store the token in local storage, but I think I'm doing something wrong and I get an error from the backend.

```
export const LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY = 'token';
```

```
import { instance } from './ApiProvider';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY } from '@/helpers/constants';

export const loginActions = async ({ email, password }) => {
  const response = instance
    .post('/api/v1/Auth/Login', {
      user: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    })

    .then((data) => {
     instance.defaults.headers.post[
       'Authorization'
     ] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY')}`; 
      return data;
    });

 

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Well, I think you should just remove the quotes around LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY, because you are giving the string itself, not the variable

Comment: unfortunately didn't help

Comment: Also try `instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY)}``

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that instance is created before you have the auth header value available and hence on subsequent call it will pass the value as undefined.

You can use axios [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for this task.

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("LOCAL_STORAGE_API_KEY"); 
    if (token) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Do have any idea how I can use this in next.js? When I create my axios instance and try to use it inside getServerSideProps or getStaticProps, I face `localStorage is not defined`. Therefore, the `Authorization` header is not set and I can not get my required response data from the backend because the GET request is not authorized.

Comment: `getServerSideProps` runs on the server. It wont have access to any browser storage. The whole point of access token based auth is that the token is saved client side. So you need to call the APIs from client side and not server side. 
You can use useEffect to call the APIs and they will have access to localStorage

Comment: So I was seeking something impossible then. My bad! Thanks for your response.